# How to check if string value is in array

Tags: arrays, swift

I am stuck on a small problem, but been lack of logic so need your help.

I have an if statement:

```
    func showButton() {
        if viewModel.model.id == Constants.Identifiers.showId[<any>] {
            //do this. Like show the button
        } else {
            //do that. Like hide the button
        }
    }
```

So the problem is that I want to check if viewmodel.model.id has any of the values in Constants.Identifiers.showId[]
model.id is a string, and Identifiers.showId[] is array of strings..

I know this is an easy, but... Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `array.contains(_:)` method. [Documentation Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2945493-contains)

```
func showButton() {
    if Constants.Identifiers.showId.contains(viewModel.model.id) {
        // do this. Like show the button
    } else {
        // do that. Like hide the button
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try it

```
if Constants.Identifiers.showId.contains(viewModel.model.id) {

}
```